# Android How do i wait for a specified time of a video

Tags: android, delay, android-videoview

I want to wait until a specified time of a video then do smthg. How can make it in android? `handler.postDelay` and `wait` comments are not sensible I think.

Comment: _wait for a specified time of a video_ Don't forget that a video might be paused, if this is from internet, it might stop to download the rest of it, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use countDownTimer

```
    Switch(v.getId()){

     case R.id.Yourid1:

     CountDownTimer test=  new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) { //count down from 3 sec to 1 sec

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //do some thing after starting timer

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            // do something after timer is finished
            }
        };


        test.start();

break;

    case R.id.YourId2:


         CountDownTimer test1=  new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) { //count down from 3 sec to 1 sec

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //do some thing after starting timer

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            // do something after timer is finished
            }
        };


        test1.start();

      }

break;
```

Comment: it's working good only once. but I cant use that code in more. how can I use it in a switch/case in each case statement. I've tried test2, test3... not worked

Comment: if in each switch case there is different thing to do then write different countdown timer in each case, i will update my code

Comment: On the timer callback, onTick,  that Redman proposes, invoke `getCurrentPosition` on the `MediaPlayer` instance to find out where in the video you actually are.

Comment: Thanks for adding break , you can accept the answer if worked  :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using android.media.MediaPlayer class for playing videos.

There are methods .getCurrentPosition()(returns current time in milliseconds) and .getDuration() (returns video duration in milliseconds) that can help you.

You can call every second(or any other time interval) .getCurrentPosition() and when it returns a specified time you can do things you need.

Same techique can be applied to Vitamio player or ExoPlayer, or any other that is able return current position.